# Dynamic package linking - using program unit in dynamic package

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe

I wrote a small component which dynamically loads a package on run-time.

So I've got some group project with my main project (`exe`) and some packages (`bpl`). Now I want to use in all of them the unit from my `exe` (`Datamod.pas`).

So in some unit's `uses` list of my package I'm adding `Datamod` and I want to access that datamod at runtime. Everything compiles, voila.

But

As I debug the code - the instance of `Datamod` class in bpl is not nil, but it gives me an AV as I'm accesing it. What am I missing? Should I export `Datamod.pas` to other package and make other packages use that package? Why it gives me an AV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access your program's unit from dynamic package.

Move datamod.pas to another package and then link it in your program and other packages. It will be accessible and it won't cause the AV.